# When to use the bitwise and operator (&)?

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, collatz

I understand that the bitwise and operator (`&`) is equivalent to a product of two bit values. When would I use it?

I am also keen to understand what `num&1` does in the code below:

```
def func(num):
    n = 1 + func((3*num+1) if num&1 else (num>>1))
    return n
```

Comment: `num&1` is the bitwise `and` of `num` and `1`. That is it tells you the value of the least significant bit in `num`.

Comment: In the code given, it checks if the lowest bit of num is set. If it is, the value is evaluated as true. In other words, it's checking if the number is even or odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments mentioned, `num&1` is a bitwise AND between `num` and `1`.

Since 1 in binary is ...000000001, the AND will result True iff the least significant bit of `num` is `1`, in other words, if it is odd ([here](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-odd-binary-numbers-end-in-1-and-even-binary-numbers-end-in-0) some explanation of binary)